# Ubuntu: No module named 'gi' when trying to get oomox working

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I'm trying to get oomox working on my ubuntu 18.04 install again. I think the issue started when I installed python. Here's the traceback I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/opt/oomox/oomox_gui/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-gi

   $ sudo apt-get install python-gi

   $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gobject
```

And some various other solutions I've found in my now 5 hour search for the answer :)

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> python3.8
>
> Ubuntu 18.04
>
> python3-gi

Package `python3-gi` provides gi for python 3.6, not 3.8